# Como obtener las filas combinadas de una columna con interop

Tags: vb.net, interop

Quisiera obtener el valor de las filas que estén combinadas de una columna dada, dejo una imagen de un ejemplo de una columna combinada en Excel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que quiero obtener es por ejemplo:

A3:A11, es decir que en ese rango cuento con celdas combinadas, estoy trabajando con InterOp y vb .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres puedes obtener el número de celdas, filas o columnas que están combinadas.

```
  Dim numeroColumnas As Integer = eHoja.Range("A3").MergeArea.Columns.Count
  Dim numeroFilas As Integer = eHoja.Range("A3").MergeArea.Rows.Count
  Dim numeroCeldas As Integer = eHoja.Range("A3").MergeArea.Count
```

Comment: Me sirvió para resolver mi problemática, solo realice una adecuación para adaptar al resultado que esperaba, muchas gracias @Otxoto por tomarte el tiempo y apoyarme.